# Access denied: 403 or 404?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

What status code should be returned if somebody request access to the entity that he is not permitted to see? You'll probably say it's 403: Forbidden. But is it common practice to return 404 instead? I don't want somebody know that this entity even exists if he is not permitted to see it. What do you think?

Comment: What would you return for a resources that does *not* exists and  which the client is not allowed to access?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use 404 Not found.

> The 404 status code can also be used in 403 scenarios, when the server
>   does not want to send back the reason why it is refusing to serve the
>   request. **A good example is when the server senses some kind of an
>   attack, which might be a brute force attack**. In this case, the
>   server responds with a 404 Not found instead of a 403 Forbidden and an
>   explanation.

Source: [Pro ASP.NET Web API Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430257822)

Answer (score 4):

Well.. it depends..

If your endpoints' URLs reveal sensitive information (e.g., in Dropbox API, you refer to files by their names, rather than their IDs - so the URLs contain the file names) or perhaps you're using sequential IDs (e.g., ascending IDs that can be brute-forced), return 404.

If you need to support a "Request Access" feature to resources you don't have permissions for, return 403, so your client-side could tell the difference.

Generally speaking, if your API uses IDs and never reveal information as part of its URLs and you're using UUIDs as IDs, I would go with 403.. as with many well-known and very secured applications nowadays (Google, Microsoft, etc..).

Comment: That's tricky because 401 could be used for that request access scenario as well. Or, you could always return 403 (as someone else suggested) and allow access requests for non-existent resources that basically just go straight to trash.

Comment: 401 could be a bad idea since it means there's an issue with _authentication_. Ie. if an automated client is using a token, and gets a 401 because of a permission issue. It might assume the token expired then re-authenticate to get a new one. Then try again, and get a 401, then re-authenticate and try again....

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example of well-known API method that returns `403` in case you have no rights on the object?

Comment: @DmitriyPopov I'd assume Google Docs should probably be such an example.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner this link refers to **write** action. But they use 404 when the user does not have **read** access to a file, or the file does not exist.  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid
I wonder what the response is if the user tries modifying a file which doesn't exist

Comment: @Grade, is it possible that the docs aren't very updated? I didn't check it lately, but here's a link that might say otherwise from the same page: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_the_user_has_not_granted_the_app_appid_verb_access_to_the_file_fileid

Answer (score 2):

Return `403 Forbidden`. If you return this for every request the client is not allowed to access and if you *never* return `404 Not Found`, the client knows nothing.

It all depends on how important this is for you:

> I don't want somebody know that this entity even exists if he is not permitted to see it.

If this really is important, always return `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: That's essentially the same as always returning 404, you've just picked a different status to return for those two scenarios. For the record if you always return 404 the client learns nothing.

Answer (score -4):

Hope you get some clarification on HTTP errors based on what I am posting below:

**HTTP 401 error ::** This error happens when a website visitor tries to access a restricted web page but isn't authorized to do so.

**HTTP 403 error ::** This error is similar to the 401 error, but note the difference between unauthorized and forbidden. This can for example happen if you try to access a directory(forbidden) on any website.

**HTTP 404 error ::** A 404 error happens when you try to access a resource on a web server (usually a web page) that doesn't exist.

Comment: :P Forgot I was not working on my home site portal. It has just the similar feature as what I just mistook! Anyway, is this answer what you're looking for?

Comment: No, it's just definition of status codes, I know what they mean.